# Error while reading and saving the excel file on serverside

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have tried the below coding for generating excel file on serverside.

**C# CODING:**

```
public void ReadandOpenExcel(DirectoryInfo outputDir)
    {

        //FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + @"\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx");

        var ExistFile = Server.MapPath("~/excelsample.xlsx");

        var File = new FileInfo(ExistFile);


        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(File))
        {
            package.Load(new FileStream(ExistFile, FileMode.Open));

            ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

            workSheet.Cells["A8"].Value = "kevin";

            package.Save();


            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=ProposalRequest.xslx");
            **Response.BinaryWrite(package.GetAsByteArray());**
            // myMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream); //works too
            Response.Flush();
            Response.Close();
        }
    }
```

While running the above code i got an error as : " **Package object was closed and disposed, so cannot carry out operations on this object or any stream opened on a part of this package.**"

**ERROR On This Line:**

> Response.BinaryWrite(package.GetAsByteArray());

Make some way for this coding to move on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it indicate which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Response.BinaryWrite(package.GetAsByteArray());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you get the bytes before you do the Save ?

```
Byte[] bin = package.GetAsByteArray();
package.Save();
```

And then use that value in the Binarywrite;

```
Response.BinaryWrite(bin);
```

Maybe it is getting closed on the `.Save()` call ?

Comment: Ok I'll Check it. @SearchAndResQ